# to string format in strftime()

Tags: php

how to make strftime return as string and not as flot/integer/double

if the timestamp is today (7-17-2011)

Then this

```
strftime('%m %d', $time);
```

... will return `07 17`

But if you remove the space in strftime like this

```
strftime('%m%d', $time);
```

... it will return `717`

How can you format the output to a string so the returned var will be `0717`?

Comment: tested it with `echo strftime('%m%d', time());` and worked as expected. Which version of php do you have? could it be an old one? where's the code you use? --- oh no enlightening: you're interpreting the result as a number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've just tested it with

```
<?php
echo strftime('%m%d', time());
?>
```

And it works. But if you interpret the result as a number, then you obtain 717 since initial 0 are not significative. You must keep it as string.

It does not happen with `%m %d` likely since the space avoid the possibility of interpreting the whole result as a number.